# Visual C++ IDE: add custom context-sensitive-helper

Tags: visual-studio, ide, context-sensitive-help

I would like to be able to get context-sensitive help for the OpenCV functions inside Visual Studio IDE (i.e. press F1 inside the editor). Does Visual Studio support adding custom help sources and if yes, how?

Thanks!